# CLLocationManager delegate not called in my project using Typhoon framework

Tags: ios, typhoon

I am using typhoon framework in my application. My application working fine. Now I want to location updates in my app. I added the Location framework and implemented the code.
But my CLLocationManger delegates method is not working.

I copied the same code in demo app witch do not have any dependency and the same code start working and I am able to get the location updates.

Does anyone can tell me what can be the possible reason of such behavior.

Here is the code that I am using:

In my LoginViewController.m   i am using following code in - (void)viewDidLoad method

```
if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Location Services Disabled", nil)
                                message:NSLocalizedString(@"You currently have all location services for this device disabled. If you proceed, you will be asked to confirm whether location services should be reenabled.", nil)
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
} else {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
     {
       NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
       UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [errorAlert show];
     }


    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
         {
            NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);              
         }
```

Comment: still having problems? the answers below did not help?

Comment: Yes, I am still facing the problem. As I mentioned in my question I copy the same code in demo project and It work perfectly..

Comment: Very, unlikely to be Typhoon related (see answer below). Though we're still happy to help. Please post some code samples.

Answer (score 0):

This does not sound related to Typhoon. We're not aware of anything in the framework that would prevent CLLocationManager from working correctly. Also, there are many published apps in the store that are using location services. In fact, [the very first Typhoon application](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/aco-virtual/id623225640?mt=8) used location services.

A common problem with location manager is forgetting to tell it to start sending updates. Be sure to do the following:

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_locationManager.delegate = self;
_locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];  //This is required!
[_locationManager startUpdatingHeading];   //This is required!
```

If you wished you could also build a location manager in Typhoon, and inject it, as long as the above to steps to start updating are called.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Typhoon, but make sure you're keeping a strong reference to the manager to keep it throughout the life time of your class, and of course to correctly assign its delegate.